# SQL Query to find missing records between two tables that share a key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just as the title asks I am trying to find a way to give me a number for the difference in transactions. The question in plain English is:
There is some bad data in the database.  Some sales transactions are missing data on which product and how many were sold.

Salestransaction (Table 1)
Columns: transactionid, customerid, storeid, tdate

Soldvia (Table 2)
Columns: transactionid, productid, noofitems

Any help on this would be appreciated. If I am being unclear let me know and I will provide more info. Thank you.

Comment: Which rdbms you use?

Comment: salestransaction.transactionid has 1351 records, and soldvia.transactionid has 1083 records. A difference of 268. How can I display this with one query?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 5):

This is simple `LEFT JOIN` with filtering `null`s:

For missing items in `Soldvia` table:

```
select count(*) as difference 
from Salestransaction st
left join Soldvia s on st.transactionid = s.transactionid 
where s.transactionid is null
```

For missing items in both tables:

```
select count(*) as difference 
from Salestransaction st
full join Soldvia s on st.transactionid = s.transactionid 
where st.transactionid is null or s.transactionid is null
```

Comment: I swear I did that. I must have screwed something up. Thanks mane.